# How to keep VSCode connection in reattched tmux session

Tags: visual-studio-code, remote-server, tmux

For a couple of months I've been using the Remote-SSH extension in VSCode to connect to a remote server. I thought of using tmux to keep track of my sessions and it all works perfect!  The issue I'm having though is `Unable to connect to VS Code Server. Error in request` showing up whenever I try using `code` in the terminal to open any files after I have reattached to a session

Comment: This is the most up-to-date information I know about this problem: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/2763. It provides a few workarounds. They don't always seem to work for everyone, but it's a place to start.